# How to properly convert characters in GB2312 to UTF-8 in PHP?

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, gb2312, mb-convert-encoding

I have variables with chinese words, their charset is GB2312. I want to convert them to UTF-8 because I want to save them to mysql table with utf-8 encoding. How to do that is PHP? I'm using PHP 7.

Here are what I have tried:

1. I have tried using `$myvar = iconv('gb2312', 'utf-8', $myvar);` However some of my variables get empty if it contains some characters (invalid UTF-8 chars maybe?)
2. I have tried using `$myvar = mb_convert_encoding($myvar, 'UTF-8', 'GB2312');` It works better than `iconv` but when `$myvar` contain some characters as I mentioned above, they turned into question mark (`?`)

Please help me, thanks

**Update**
Here is an example of my chinese string:

- GB2312 (Expected result): 第3章︰林鴻
- Using `mb_convert_encoding` become: 第3章?林?
- Using `iconv` become empty

Comment: Please provide a sample of a string that "doesn't work", perhaps in `"\x..\x.."` notation to ensure it reflects your encoding accurately.

Comment: @deceze: I have added sample above, can you help me?

Comment: Please provide the *bytes* of that string. It seems to not be possible to convert that string from Unicode to GB2312, so it's unclear what exact string you're really working with.